# .exe file in S3 Browser does not work when the user downloads it via the S3 web link file and starts the installation

Tags: windows, flutter, amazon-s3, exe, mime-types

I created an .exe file from a Windows application made with Flutter and uploaded it to the S3 browser in a bucket. This works but then when someone downloads the file via the URL provided by S3 and runs the file, the installation does not start. Sometimes the file even deletes itself when it is run. This is strange because I have tried sending the same file to users with other tools and it works.

I first tried to change the permissions that can be seen in the S3 browser as "Full Control", "Read" or "Write" but without result. I then changed the MIME type of the file to be the same at the origin of the file and in the S3 browser, namely "application/x-dosexec". It was not known to the S3 browser, so I added it but it didn't change anything. I also checked the checksum before uploading to S3 and after uploading and it was the same. Any ideas ?

Comment: Does the download start and finish successfully? Most likely the file is marked as "not trustworthy" and deleted either by the browser or an anti vurs software.

Comment: Thank you for your comment ! Yes, the download starts and ends successfully. On Edge when the file is downloaded, the browser asks to be sure to download the file and it is possible to keep the file and after the download works fine. Either the file is deleted when the user runs the file in Windows Explorer or nothing happens.